# Read key-value pairs from AWS Secret Manager into an array in Bash

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, jq, aws-secrets-manager

How to get secret key/value from aws secret manager. I am using the following bash script which doesn't give the expected result

```
#/bin/bash

secretList=$(aws secretsmanager get-secret-value --secret-id test | jq --raw-output '.SecretString' | jq -r "to_entries|map(\"\(.key)=\(.value|tostring)\")|.[]")


echo $secretList


for key in "${!secretList[@]}"
do
  echo "Key = $key"
  echo "Value  = ${secretList[$key]}"
done
```

Current result is

```
test=test123 test2=sdf543
Key = 0
Value  = test=test123
test2=sdf543
```

Expected result is

```
Key = test
Value  = test123

Key = test2
Value  = sdf543
```

Help with this is much appreciated